# Power Query - Transposing multiple rows into singular columns

Tags: powerquery

I am a complete newbie to Power Query. I am trying to take the following data source and convert the field into aggregated headers with a singular value of the code.

[image]

I've tried utilizing group by, transposing and merging duplicated data sources but I'm not able to get the desired result. I'm expecting something like below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click select the Field column, then transform .. pivot column...

use Value as Values column and in advanced options choose Dont Aggregate

[image]

sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(Source[Field]), "Field", "Value")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Amazing how I can struggle for an hour and the answer is so simple. Thank you.

Comment: Most things are simple after you know them. Keep on truckin'